# Are there ultrasonic transducers which are able to produce a "chirp" sound wave?

Tags: arduino-uno, frequency, sound, components

I'm working in a ultrasonic radar project and the supervising teacher wants us to produce a chirp sound wave (a frequency-varying sinusoid).

I'm familiarised with the usual ultrasonic module, but as far as I know, it cannot do the task.

I searched on-line for transducers that I could use, but couldn't find anything useful.
Are there any commercially available component that could do this task? If not, what could I possibly do?

Comment: Ultrasonic chirp, or an (human) audible chirp? It sound to me like the teacher doesn't know what he/she is talking about.

Comment: Why won't usual ultrasoud modules work - are they physically limited to a narrow range of frequencies? (I know they are usually run at a particular frequency, but if driven at other frequencies there might still be a measurable response - is it just a case of doing some tests?)

Comment: The most common ultrasonic modules for Arduino use have self-contained pulse generation and detection (actually done by abusing a serial line driver charge pump chip!)  To build a chirp system you would need transducer(s) with a suitable bandwith, and either a chirp generator/detector or interface/conversion circuitry to put a DSP algorithm in those roles.

Answer (score 1):

Piezoelectric speakers, the kind commonly found in ultrasonic transducers generally operate in a narrow frequency range when operating at ultrasonic range (a resonate frequency of the metallic diaphragm). This is very true once you get above about ~60 kHz. However if the ultrasonic "chirp" you are looking for can be in the range of say 20-60 kHz you could be in luck, i.e., http://www.conrad-electronic.co.uk/ce/en/product/710991/KEPO-piezo-element-25-60-kHz-515-mm

You could use the Tone function (which goes up to 65535 Hz) to produce the frequency sweep you desire. However if you want to go up to frequencies in the 100+ kHz range you will be delving into research territory and hence extremely expensive equipment.

Having said that, technologies change very quickly and I my knowledge may already be out of date. Hope this helps.